# Nested JSON response TypeError

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a JSON response, one that I can't figure out. Here is my current response that I receive.

[image]

This is my ajax script:

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click', '#pullDetails', function() {
         $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/carrier/claims/pullDetails',
            data: {
                num: $('input[name=proNumber]').val(),
                _token: $('input[name=_token]').val()},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.details != undefined) {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(data.details.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.Name); //result: ATLAS INTL
                        $('#carrierReturnData').html(data.details.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.Name);
                    }else{
                        console.log('failed');
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(data.details.SearchResults.SearchItem); 
                    }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now my question is how would I get the specific data from the line "SearchItem" (on the first line of the response json)?

At the moment I get the following: `TypeError: data.details.SearchResults` is undefined, but data.details is recognized as my console logs "success."

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a JSON.parse of details and then try to log SearchResults

```
var results = JSON.parse(data.details);
console.log(results.SearchResults.SearchItem);
```

Comment: That specifically returns success (as part of the first portion) and then undefined. However (and I'll edit my question above to include the images), if I remove the .SearchItem and just keep it as results.SearchResults, I get an array returned. Give me a few moments...

Comment: I've added images to show what the console return looks like.

Comment: Using your suggestion above, I edited to work as such: results.SearchResults[0].SearchItem.